# How much data can hold CoAP in single message?

Tags: coap

What is the limit of size in sending data in CoAP for single message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CoAP implementation usually introduces its own max message size setting (hence a default value).

For more info how to choose the proper limit in a particular case, please refer to point 4.5 of RFC 7252:

[RFC 7252 - The Constrained Application Protocol (CoAP)][1]

Quoting it:

> 

The CoAP specification itself provides only an upper bound to the message size.
Messages larger than an IP packet result in undesirable packet fragmentation.
A CoAP message, appropriately encapsulated, SHOULD fit within a
single IP packet (i.e., avoid IP fragmentation) and (by fitting into
one UDP payload) obviously needs to fit within a single IP datagram.
If the Path MTU is not known for a destination, an IP MTU of 1280
bytes SHOULD be assumed; if nothing is known about the size of the
headers, good upper bounds are 1152 bytes for the message size and
1024 bytes for the payload size.

Also it depends on network stack implementation:

> 

Implementation Note:  CoAP's choice of message size parameters works
well with IPv6 and with most of today's IPv4 paths.  (However,
with IPv4, it is harder to absolutely ensure that there is no IP
fragmentation.  If IPv4 support on unusual networks is a
consideration, implementations may want to limit themselves to
more conservative IPv4 datagram sizes such as 576 bytes; per
[RFC0791], the absolute minimum value of the IP MTU for IPv4 is as
low as 68 bytes, which would leave only 40 bytes minus security
overhead for a UDP payload.  Implementations extremely focused on
this problem set might also set the IPv4 DF bit and perform some
form of path MTU discovery [RFC4821]; this should generally be
unnecessary in realistic use cases for CoAP, however.)  A more
important kind of fragmentation in many constrained networks is
that on the adaptation layer (e.g., 6LoWPAN L2 packets are limited
to 127 bytes including various overheads); this may motivate
implementations to be frugal in their packet sizes and to move to
block-wise transfers [BLOCK] when approaching three-digit message
sizes.

```
If you want to send large messages, there is another specification.

[RFC 7959: Block-Wise Transfers in the Constrained Application Protocol (CoAP)][2]

Most of popular implementations implement this specification as well.


  [1]: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7252
  [2]: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7959
```